# Excel 2007 VBA Cell.interior alternating based on Consecutive Cell Calculation To target

Tags: vba, excel

I will do what I can to make this short and sweet. I have an excel Work sheet that needs to sum cells until it reaches the target. Then those cells need an interior color set. The calculations then reset then continue down the range until the next run of cells equals target. The interior should the set to a different color for this set. This would alternate through the range. I have it about 90 % but the second color only highlights for the start of the set and then continues with the first color. Thank you in advance for any pointers

I have :

```
Sub calctarget()
    Dim x As Variant
    Dim xsub As Variant
    Dim total  As Double
    Dim y As Variant
    Dim target As Double
    Dim RunTotal As Double

    target = 44500

    If RunTotal < target Then y = 0
    RunTotal = 0
    For Each y In Range("a1:a15")
        On Error Resume Next
        RunTotal = RunTotal + y.Value
        If RunTotal < target Then
            y.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
        End If
        If RunTotal > target Then
            RunTotal = RunTotal - y
            If y.Offset(-1, 0).Interior.ColorIndex = 4 Then
                RunTotal = 0
                If RunTotal = 0 Then y.Interior.ColorIndex = 5
                RunTotal = RunTotal + y
            End If
        End If
    Next y
End Sub
```

Comment: I have changed the indentation to make it easier to read - can you check this is what you meant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is maybe what you need (it alternates colors every time the target is reached and carries the balance forward if any):

```
Sub calctarget()
    Dim c As Range
    Dim target As Double
    Dim runTotal As Double
    Dim currentColor As Long

    target = 44500
    currentColor = 4

    For Each c In Range("a1:a15")
        If IsNumeric(c) Then
            runTotal = runTotal + c
        End If
        If runTotal >= target Then 'Target reached
            currentColor = IIf(currentColor = 4, 5, 4) 'alternate colors (4 and 5)
            runTotal = runTotal - target 'maybe you want to start from 0 again?
        End If
        c.Interior.ColorIndex = currentColor
    Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: Cool that gets me a step closer. The calculation is off a little though. The second set runs> then target. This is in essence building a truck load out of sets of product weight. The cells have to sum consecutively to follow an out bound schedule. So once cells have summed as close as they can to target without going over, that would be one load. the next set will start at 0 again until reaching as close to target. rinse/repeat..  This gets me very close just got to figure out the calc..   Thank you

Comment: @PCGIZMO You just need to change `runTotal = runTotal - target` to `runTotal = 0`

Comment: Whoops hit enter before I typed. I have added a link with what it should look like and the comparison of our two codes. two what i am trying to get if you want take a look . but thank you for the help so far i have been playing with what you posted trying to get the Sum to show correct vs the interior color. at the moment the first set runs as it should second set runs 1 cell over for highlighting and compared to total .

Comment: @PCGIZMO OK I had misunderstood: you need to change `runTotal = runTotal - target` to `runTotal = c`

Comment: Haaaa the one thing i did not change when trying to work it out . WOO HOO thanks. I'm not much of a programmer but it was either learn or do this with 5000 + cells manually . Thanks again